# Please help solving the equation $(2x+1)^2-3(x+1)^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am doing exercises to practice for finals. Please help solve the equation $$(2x+1)^2-3(x+1)^2=0$$

I tried solving it but I got to $x^2-2x-2=0$ and I got stuck there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the quadratic formula?

Comment: Ah!! I forgot about it. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), that is, an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Use the general formula:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
There may be 0, 1 or 2 solutions (depending on the sign of $b^2-4ac$).

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-2x-2=0\implies (x-1)^2-3=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nope, i cant take it from there

Comment: $(x-1)^2=3\implies x-1=\pm\sqrt3$; [completing the square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) can be used to solve quadratic equations and derive the quadratic formula